# rails javascript correct syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to change the color of a button with javascript.

Almost all the tips say:

(in `application.js`)

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(this).css({"background-color":"#ff0000"});
});
```

but it doesn't work. I have to code in this way:

```
$(function() {
  return $(".btn").click(function(e) {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"#ff0000"});
  });
});
```

Why does not work with the first code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens due to `turbolinks` in rails 4, try this

```
var ready = function(){
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"#ff0000"});
  });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

For more info on turbolinks, refer this http://asciicasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks

Comment: I tried, it works @rsb. My second code also works, I didn't understand why the first one doesn't. I understand that is for javascript. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: When we use Turbolinks this callback is only triggered on the initial page load. This means that if we start on another page then move to the page for a task the DOM’s ready event isn’t fired as we’re still technically on the same HTML page. There are several events that Turbolinks will trigger, one of which is called page:load.

Comment: Ooops @rsb, I wanted to say "for turbolinks"